# Broken link when displaying image

Tags: php, image

I can't find the reason why my picture won't show.

```
<?php
$dir = "/home/ahmed/Desktop/uploaded";
if($opendir = opendir($dir))
{
    while (($file = readdir($opendir)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            echo "<img src='$dir/$file'><br>";      
        }
    }
}
?>
```

When I checked the uploaded directory, all images were locked. I gave full permission to every image but my image still won't be displayed. I've been messing around with this for about 30 min and I still cannot find a solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `/home/ahmed/Desktop/uploaded` is an absolute path. you must use a relative path to the vhost you are in..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a path relative to the site's `DocumentRoot` value, if this is currently set to `/home/ahmed/Desktop` then your img tag's src value would resolve as `uploads/img.jpg` for example.

If you're using Apache the `DocumentRoot` is typically defined in the site's Virtual Host config file.